# I want to use data table jquery after ajax load data but my jquery is running before the ajax load. In dataservice i have ajax call for data

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
        <thead>
            <tr class="success">

                <th>AccountName</th>
                <th>AccountSite</th>
                <th>ParentAccount</th>
                <th>AccountNumber</th>
                <th>AnnualRevenue</th>
                <th>Employees</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>AccountType</th>
                <th>Ownerships</th>
                <th>Industry</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: allaccounts">
            <tr class="active">
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: AccountName"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: AccountSite"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: ParentAccount"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: AccountNumber"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html:AnnualRevenue"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: Employees"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: Rating"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: AccountType"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: Ownerships"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label data-bind="html: Industry"></label>
                </td>
                <td><a data-bind="attr:{href:'/account/addedit/'+AccountId}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a data-bind="attr:{href:'/account/SeeDetails/'+AccountId}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Details</a></td>
                <td><a data-bind="click: $root.delete" onclick=" Reloadpage()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

at this page i am writing the jquery add the script in wich i have called the ajax 
and for ajax i use data service , datacontext and view model

```
getallaccountforgrid = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/account/GetAllAccountForGrid",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    if (data && data.IsSuccess) {
       dataContext.allaccounts(data.Data);
    }
   })
   .fail(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

the above is the data service code

```
allaccounts = ko.observableArray([]),
return allaccounts :allaccounts
```

the above code is data context code
after this i am using view model to connect
data is loading correctly bt issue is that jquery is ruuning before ajax load data

Comment: You need to say what libraries you are using. Knockout?

Comment: Make the `.done` function call the allaccounts code.